# SSH a Windows 10 VM from Ubuntu OS

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, wireless-bridge

I have two computers. The OS of the first one is Ubuntu and I am using a Windows VM (VirtualBox) on the second computer. I use a `Bridge Adapter` with the VM. Right now I am able to ping the VM, but if I want to SSH, I got `port 22: Connection Refused`. Be aware that the firewall is off on the VM. I also installed Bash/Ubuntu on that VM so that I can use Linux command lines. `openssh-server` is preinstalled when I installed Bash/Ubuntu.

I tried to connect to my VM with `ssh username@ip_address`.

In that scenario, what is the best way to SSH the Windows 10 VM from Ubuntu?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Actually, I can SSH from my Win10 VM to Ubuntu, but not the opposite.

[image]

In the Settings > Apps, OpenSSH-Client and OpenSSh-Server are already installed :

[image]

Comment: in order to diagnose this issue, you must supply, the exact command you are using to establish the SSH connection.

Comment: Have you [enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) the OpenSSH server on Windows 10?

Comment: Is there a firewall rule allowing SSH?

Comment: Rule allowing SSH has been deactivated? Then no SSH. Or firewall deactivated?

Comment: Is OpenSSH starting at Windows 10 start?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I have updated the question

Comment: Can you SSH into the VM from its host?

Comment: You need to enable the Windows 10 OpenSSH server, not the Ubuntu (WSL) one.

Comment: No, I can't SSH from its host nor the Ubuntu machine. I can SSH my Ubuntu machine from the Win10 VM, but not the opposite

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sincerely I don't even understand what you mean by enable the Windows 10 OpenSSH server. I have installed bash/ubuntu on Win10 and from there I have installed openssh-server

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I have updated the question

Comment: J Doe look here:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the Windows 10 OpenSSH server, not the Ubuntu (WSL) one. Follow the steps on this page:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse